# hacer un Horizontal Card con Bootstrap 5 para moviles

Tags: bootstrap, css3, responsive, bootstrap-5

estoy tratando de implementar las cards en horizontal (y que se queden así) para el diseño móvil ya que quiero logar algo como DiDi con los productos, uso a esta app como ejemplo ya que no he visto a nadie implementarlas como quiero ya que al momento de hacerlas responsivo pasan a vertical. Logre hacer que se quedaran así (horizontal) pero no se ven muy responsivas que digamos:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 500px; max-height: 150px;">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-5" >
                    <img src="img/cards/cuadrada1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-7">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo resolví de la siguiente manera, me di cuenta que lo único que estaba haciendo era confundir el tamaño de la imagen con mi .col

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="row g-0 d-flex">
          <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid h-100" src="img/cards/cuadrada1.jpg" alt="..." width="200">
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in</p>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="row g-0 d-flex">
          <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid h-100" src="img/cards/cuadrada1.jpg" alt="..." width="200">
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in</p>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

lo que hice para hacer que la imagen ocupara todo el alto del .col fue darle la clase:

```
class="img-fluid h-100"
```

y de esa forma el tamaño del alto de la imagen se iría adaptando al .col